# Python multilevel inheritance initialize only the base class

Tags: python

```
class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("s")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("s1")
        super().__init__()


class C(B):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

C()
```

Here i am initializing the B class but i want to initialize the base class A alone in this case . how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super) function has a two-argument form.

> ```
> super([type[, object-or-type]])
> ```

If given two arguments `type` and `obj`, `super` returns a bound object representing a version of `obj` whose superclass resolution will begin at `type`. Normally, `super().__init__()` in `C` is basically equivalent to `super(C, self).__init__()`. But you can supply `B` as the starting point for method resolution to only consider things further in the MRO than `B`.

```
class C(B):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(B, self).__init__()
```

That being said, there are very few use cases for this. If you're partially initializing an object and trying to monkeypatch one of its parents, then that's a very good sign that `C` should not be a subclass of `B`, or that your architecture has bigger flaws. So, generally, if you find yourself in this situation, consider refactoring.